# A domain that redirects to my site is ranked higher

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

I have recently migrated my hosting provider and realised that when I did I had a lot of domains that didn't point anywhere or weren't in use. During the migration I just decided to 301 them all towards my blog rather than just have them being unused.

As it turns out, over the course of the last 3 days one of these domains is now more highly ranked than my blog and I'm not sure what's happening.

If you Google my name I want my blog to appear as high up as possible: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=scott+helme.

My blog is the 2nd result (for me) and should be `scotthelme.co.uk` and not `eve-bay.co.uk` which is showing as if it were my blog. What has happened here? I wouldn't think a 301 would cause this behaviour and what remedy would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eve-bay.co.uk` gives a `301 Moved Permanently` to your actual site, `scotthelme.co.uk`, and in some browsers and searches your site is the one that appears in the result, no evidence of the "old" one.

With that 301 redirect, Google will soon remove it from SERPs.

Oh, one more thing, your canonical is pointing to http://www.scotthelme.co.uk, and you're actually 301 redirecting `http://www.scott..` to `http://scott..`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know what would cause me to see the 'eve-bay domain then? Can I expect it to take long to clear out?

Comment: I guess that Google had indexed previously that domain before actually indexing your blog. eve-bay was last [cached on Sep. 13th](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:vhrLq5n3F9MJ:www.eve-bay.co.uk/&hl=en&gl=uk&strip=0) scotthelme on [Sep 23th](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:zoHBgefGpiEJ:https://www.scotthelme.co.uk/+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)

Comment: Try creating a Google Webmaster account for `eve-bay` and request to remove the url https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/164734?hl=en, or place a robots.txt in its root `eve-bay.co.uk/robots.txt` blocking the access to all crawlers

Comment: @ScottHelme You might check for backlinks for that domain, which could cause it to be pushed up higher.

Comment: @dan I thought about that but it was hardly even used. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @I.G.Pascual Both done :-)

Comment: As far as I know, using robots.txt to block all crawlers from eve-bay is a bad move. Google won't crawl it anymore, it'll miss half (or probably more) of your 301 redirects and it won't transfer any link juice from the old pages to the new ones. The old site will get removed just fine, but the new site will have to start from scratch and all of the links to your old site will be useless.